# Finding generators and relations for special commutative algebras with a computer

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra

Let $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables and $a_1,...,a_m$ elements in the quotient field $K(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Let $A:=K[a_1,...,a_m]$ the ring generated by the $a_i$ in $K(x_1,...,x_n)$.
We can write $A=K[y_1,...,y_r]/I$ coming from a surjection $K[y_1,...,y_r] \rightarrow A$ with $y_i$ mapping to some of the $a_i$ and $I$ are the resulting relations.

> Question: Is there an existing method for a computer algebra system (such as singular) to calculate a minimal $r$ such that a presentation of $A$ as above exists and also find the $I$ in a quick way?

Comment: Of course we can find $I$ with $r=m$ by clearing denominators in the $y_i-a_i$, then eliminating the $x$ variables using Gröbner bases in $K[x,y]$. From there I guess you’re looking for the embedding dimension of the scheme defined by $I$. There should be some way to compute the affine span of the scheme without too much trouble.